# Bootstrap datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use the datetimepicker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function"

Here are my includes:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>                       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
```

Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
            $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
            });
            $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });
            $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any other errors in the JS console?

Comment: no, thats the only one

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/cfwat90p/ (that's exactly your code, including the missing `bootstrap.min.css`, but a missing CSS-file doesn't cause a JS-error)

Comment: My problem was where I did the includes.  It's a flask app, and it wouldn't let me include the js files (other than jQuery) in the links block of the child template.

Comment: I have same problem, but only on some severs (same war).. Have tried all orders of includes, no solution found.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Below is the right code. Include JS files in following manner:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
      useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
    });
    $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function(e) {
      $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function(e) {
      $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<body>



  <div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I had to move the includes/javascript around a bit because its a flask app, but this order worked.  Thanks

Comment: Happy coding @user3784402

Comment: I surrender,  too many dependencies, I could write my own before figuring out why this isn't working; I followed the order of files to the letter, still not working; going to look for something with one include

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you have not included `bootstrap.min.css`. Also, the sequence of imports could be causing issue. Please try rearranging your resources as following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>                       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wq42w8w2/)

Comment: @user3784402, make sure, you have included bootstrap css file.

Comment: I use this sequence, but still no luck.  It used to work, now is broken with datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: Share you fiddle, let me check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use datepicker/ timepicker instead of datetimepicker like:

replace:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

with:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker(); // or timepicker for time picker
```

Comment: didn't work, plus all the examples say use datetimepicker(); this control sucks, too many dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I changed the import sequence without fixing the problem, until finally I installed moments and tempus dominius (Core and bootrap), using npm and include them in boostrap.js

```
try {
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('moment'); /*added*/
require('bootstrap');
require('tempusdominus-bootstrap-4');/*added*/} catch (e) {}
```