# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined when loading bootstrap date time picker in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

When I am adding the bootstrap date time picker, the calendar when clicking on the "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" is not loading, have added all the files but it shows the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at 1:417

**view page:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">         
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-sm-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>      

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/assets/js/jquery.min.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
           "~/assets/js/jquery.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"
            ));
```

**dafault.cshtml** page (layout page)

```
 @Styles.Render("~/css/bootstrap")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Why is the calendar is not loading when clicking on the link and the generating in the $ jquery, I think I have correctly given the code and scripts. can anyone please help me to find the solution ??

Comment: very obviously, you've got two bundles called "jquery" declared. First, try removing the duplicate and see if that helps. Looks like moment is included twice too (once in the bundles and once in the HTML)

Comment: As a side note, your bundles should have the non-minified versions (so the full version is rendered in debug mode, and the minified version is automatically be loaded in release mode)

Comment: after giving the minified version, also it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datetimepicker is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263021/bootstrap-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, move the `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();` to `$( document ).ready`:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Also - You are trying to use JQuery functionality before loading it.

In your `BundleConfig.cs`, include JQuery first:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/assets/js/jquery.min.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"));
...
Other includes
...
```

And in your `dafault.cshtml` page, change the rendering order and leave the `bootstrap css` for last:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Styles.Render("~/css/bootstrap")
```

Comment: but after giving as u said the calendar is not loading as earlier and showing another error 1:423 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function in the script why is that ?

Comment: yes I have given and shown in my question but it shows the error in  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();  ?? why is it so ?

Comment: Try moving the 
`$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();`  only after `$( document ).ready(...)`

Comment: Sry, can you please tell how to give , I didn't understand

Comment: the same error is repeating Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker1 is not a function ??

Comment: Is this site available to see online ?

Comment: No, Iam just building it

Comment: what is the "1" in the end ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I have 1 more problem, that the date choose by calender is not saving in the database , why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) for js files