# datetimepicker is not a function : bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am having issues with datepicker bootstrap3. The error I am getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

I literally copy pasted the code from the documentation page yet having error. 
Here is the code on js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/000owh6a/

Here is the documentation https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

UPDATE: bootstrap-datepicker version updated. Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/000owh6a/3/

Comment: Comment in my answer should give you the right setup now. One recommendation: check this out, it's actively being developed and really nice https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatpickr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a really really old version of the picker, version 1.6.4. In your code you have:
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js`

The current version is 4.17.47 https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Get the current version from here and try it: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/build/js

**Edit**: you also need to load moment.js, before bootstrap-datepicker. Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dkv4rq6w/2/

Comment: I have found the 4th version of bootstrap yet not working

Comment: @Lucas not bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker. If you have the current version of bootstrap-datepicker and it's still not working, comment with your jsfiddle

Comment: @Lucas Ah, now you're just missing one more thing, take a look at the console errors. You need to load moment.js too, before bootstrap-datepicker `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>` https://jsfiddle.net/q3g2k14w/

Comment: One other thing, Do you know why it is time picker instead of datepicker

Comment: @Lucas maybe, two things. See my comments here https://jsfiddle.net/dkv4rq6w/4/  This is why people like to use flatpickr, and packages that don't have dependencies. Imagine you want to update to new jquery or moment.js or bootstrap.js version....any of these updates might break bootstrap-datepicker!

Comment: @Lucas and here is your same question, there are CDN links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263021/bootstrap-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function?rq=1

Comment: You are right I am changing to flatpickr. It is so simple

Answer (score 0):

How are you bringing jQuery in? I’m not seeing it being imported in your document.

Comment: its being loaded via jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

you can place this part this part of script after your target element:

```
<!-- your target element -->
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker1" />
<!-- script to place after the target element -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

scripts execute after all html document have been loaded. or you can use $(document).ready(function(){}); to load the script once page is completely loaded.

EDIT:
as @user2035552 mentioned, how you place the jquery file on your code? you need that file to make those plugin scripts work.

Comment: its being loaded via jsfiddle