# Unable to display datetimepicker for this version of bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display datetimepicker for the textbox, I might be missing some bootstrap links, can anyone identify them for me? thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label col text-right "><b>Created At:</b></label>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center" id='datetimepicker4' />

  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label col text-right"><b>Updated At:</b></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id="name" class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263021/bootstrap-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: You are importing jQuery twice. Only 1 is required.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label col text-right "><b>Created At:</b></label>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <input type='date' class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center"  />

  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label col text-right"><b>Updated At:</b></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id="name" class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you wont require js to display date picker you will require js to set the max date to today.

Comment: hi, is there any datetimepicker that has this format , "2020-01-18 12:00PM" thanks in advance

Comment: try  type="datetime-local"

Comment: where should I insert this line in?

Comment: <input type='datetime-local' class="form-control col-sm-15 row align-items-center justify-content-center"  />

Answer (score 0):

You are adding jQuery twice. Remove one.

Add these 2 js -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you have the css added to get the expected view.

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263021/bootstrap-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function) may be helpful.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> I've removed the following jquery, and inserted 2 extra lines, but I could only display the date format upon clicking but unable to show the date for me to pick from.